# How to interpret a discrete variable in regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics

I have a regression model where the dependent variable is logarithm of `miles per gallon` and several IVs. One of the IVs is `origin` of the car where 1=USA, 2=Europe, 3=Japan.

I wonder how to interpret the results of the model if the beta parameter for the variable `origin` is 0.040.

Furthermore isn't it better to transform the variable `origin` to 3 dummy variables `USA, Europe and Japan?`

The dataset comes from [here.](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG)

Comment: You should indeed use indicator or dummy variables for origin coded 1, 2, 3. The codes are quite arbitrary and the information should be represented using indicator variables. It's far from obvious that miles per gallon should be logged....

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow you :/ So I should transform the discrete variable to three dummy ones? What do you mean by miles per gallon should be logged?

Comment: Yes; you should use indicator variables, as stated. I am questioning why you are logging miles per gallon, not recommending it.

Comment: Now I see. I have transformed the mpg because of heteroskedasticity in the data.

Comment: A better motive would be getting closer to linearity. Working with gallons/mile often helps as this is closer to underlying physics.

Comment: @Adasz Take a look at the first part of [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/93103/7071).