# When predicting using a model with log(target) is there a built in helper for back transformation?

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, linear-model

Suppose I have a simple linear model in r of the form `linear_mod <- lm(log(target) ~ a + b + c)`.

I am able to predict() with this model by predicting on my training data, back transforming the prediction results for `log(target)` using `exp()` and then manually calculating an evaluation metric such as RMSE.

I wondered if there's any framework or setting I can use to tell r to backtransform automatically, like when I call `summary(linear_mod)` where r returns the RMSE as well as R squared.

Is there a package (e.g. caret?) that can accept as a argument whether or not to back transform the target variable when using a transformation? Or must I do this manually, perhaps by creating a function?

Comment: Search for "Duan Smearing." Here's [a good example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93089/reporting-regression-statistics-after-logarithmic-transformation) of what you have to do.

Comment: What quantity are you trying to obtain when you transform back? What assumptions are you making on the log scale? (whatever you're looking for a prediction of it's probably already answered on site)

Comment: Hi @Glen_b I was interested in RMSE as well as having predict return the backtransformed values rather than the log values. Is this "standard practice"? See also for example this post on kdnuggets I found while researching. On the last paragraph of page 1, the author compares RMSE of a log model to a regular model. This confused me since I thought it was not comparable. Have I misunderstood the article? https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/10/learn-generalized-linear-models-glm-r.html

Comment: You're missing what I am asking. What do your predicted values represent? Are you trying to get expected values or something else?

Comment: I believe I'm seeking both expected values as well as evaluation metric. I understand how to do this manually by predicting on the data, back transforming the results (thus expected values) and then calculating RMSE. However I wondered that this must be such a common task that perhaps predict() function or a package might have a way to automatically return back transformed predictions and evaluation metric with a log(target variable) type of linear model?