# backtransform confidence intervals from a log-transformed linear regression model

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, back-transformation

I have a linear regression model with violated assumptions (linearity and Constant variance), thus I decided to take the log of the dependent variable and this step solved the problem.

Afterwards, the coefficient of the independent variable (BMI) was:

```
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          1.249998   0.342765   3.647  0.00032 ***
i$BMI               -0.017679   0.011301  -1.564  0.11892  



                     2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)          0.57510785 1.92488723
i$BMI               -0.03992972 0.00457222
```

I exponentiated the coefficient (-0.017679 ) and reported the coefficient as (0.9824764)

the confidence intervals were ( -0.03992972 to 0.00457222) and when I exponentiate them, they became (0.960857 to 1.004583). the new intervals don't include 0 which means it is significant while the p.value is over 0.05. Thus, I assume they are wrong.

please, advise on how to handle this and report the right CIs.

Comment: Why do you have the logistic tag? Is the outcome binary? The multiplicative vs additive effects difference has been covered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/93103/7071).

Comment: no, I just removed the tag.

Comment: Hints about how to think about this.  1. Is it possible to exponentiate a number and get a negative number as a result?  Think carefully!  2.  Let's assume the estimated coefficient of BMI was exactly equal to zero.  Would it be significantly different from zero?  3.  What is $\exp\{0\}$?

Comment: exactly, that's the challenge. Don't know how to go about that!

Comment: Try answering the questions, that should help!